# How can I run a game starting with Commoners?

Tags: dnd-5e

My gaming group tends to prefer low power level campaigns. Rather than tales of epic heroes saving the world, we prefer tales of dirt-farming peasants sometimes succeeding at things. We tend to be much more invested in out characters when we feel they are defying the odds.

My question is: Using 5e as base, how can I incorporate starting a campaign with the party as a Commoner or other NPC class (effectively Lvl 0) and have them eventually progress into real classes after the first few seasons?

How can I adjust starting characteristics and gear to represent this?

I welcome all suggestions, comments, and advice.

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! Take the [tour], if you have the time and you can see what makes SE different from the traditional forum and other Q&A sites. Your question was marked as a duplicate, it's already been answered in the linked question (which is a neat feature that makes SE stand out from forums and other Q&A sites). Don't worry, you're not in trouble; we like duplicates. Anyway, if the answers in the linked question doesn't answer your question, please edit the question to be more distinct. Welcome again :)